# Parallel exists function in F#

Tags: f#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

### Motivation

I have a long-running boolean function which should be executed in an array and I want to return immediately if an element in the array satisfies the condition. I would like to do the search in parallel and terminate other threads when the first complete thread returns an correct answer.

### Question

What is a good way to implement parallel exists function in F#? Since my goal is performance, an efficient solution is preferred to an easy or idiomatic one.

### Test case

Suppose that I want to find whether one value exists in an array or not. And the comparison function (`equals`) is simulated as a computation-expensive one:

```
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Threading

// Source at http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/releases/view/50473
let doCpuIntensiveOperation seconds (token:CancellationToken) throwOnCancel =
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) then
            if (throwOnCancel) then token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
            false
        else
            let ms = int64 (seconds * 1000.0)
            let sw = new Stopwatch()
            sw.Start()
            let checkInterval = Math.Min(20000000, int (20000000.0 * seconds))

            // Loop to simulate a computationally intensive operation
            let rec loop i = 
                // Periodically check to see if the user has requested 
                // cancellation or if the time limit has passed
                let check = seconds = 0.0 || i % checkInterval = 0
                if check && token.IsCancellationRequested then
                    if throwOnCancel then token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                    false
                elif check && sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > ms then
                    true
                else 
                  loop (i + 1)

            // Start the loop with 0 as the first value
            loop 0

let inline equals x y =
    doCpuIntensiveOperation 0.01 CancellationToken.None false |> ignore
    x = y
```

The array consists of 1000 randomly generated elements and the searching value is guaranteed in the 2nd half of the array (so sequential search has to go through at least a half of the array):

```
let rand = new System.Random()
let m = 1000
let N = 1000000
let xs = [|for _ in 1..m -> rand.Next(N)|]
let i = rand.Next((m-1)/2, m-1);;

#time "on";;
let b1 = parallelExists (equals xs.[i]) xs;; // Parallel
let b2 = Array.exists (equals xs.[i]) xs;; // Sequential
```

Comment: I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: If the element is guaranteed to be in the second half of the array, why not search on the ``.[xs.Length/2..]`` slice (which copies the array btw) or start searching at xs.Length/2.

Comment: It's just an example to avoid the scenario that the search terminates too early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can take the following steps:

1. Spawn a number of workers (threads or async computations), and pass each an equal slice of the array and a cancellation token which will be shared by all workers
2. When a worker finds the searched item, it calls Cancel on the token (each worker should check the cancel state of the token on each iteration and bail if needed)

I don't have time at the moment to write the code, so there could be some detail I'm omitting.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6804733/162396), and related question, may be helpful.

#### UPDATE

This is an example of what I'm thinking

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks

let getChunks size array =
  let rec loop s n =
    seq {
      if n > 0 then
        let r = n - size
        if r > 0 then yield (s, size); yield! loop (s + size) r
        else yield (s, size + r)
    }      
  loop 0 (Array.length array)

[<Literal>]
let CHUNK_SIZE = 3

let parallelExists f (array:_[]) =
  use cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
  let rec checkSlice i n = 
    if n > 0 && not cts.IsCancellationRequested then
      if f array.[i] then cts.Cancel()
      else checkSlice (i + 1) (n - 1)
  let workers =
    array
    |> getChunks CHUNK_SIZE
    |> Seq.map (fun (s, c) -> Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> checkSlice s c))
    |> Seq.toArray
  try 
    Task.WaitAll(workers, cts.Token)
    false
  with :? OperationCanceledException -> true
```

Usage

```
let array = Array.init 10 id
let exists = 
  array |> parallelExists (fun i ->
    Thread.Sleep(500)
    i = 9)
printfn "%b" exists //true
```

Comment: This would work but `async` makes no attempt to exploit locality so the cache behaviour would be bad and, consequently, it won't scale as well as it could on a multicore because the bottleneck will be IO to shared memory.

Comment: Your idea is nice but `async` is not really suitable to my scenario. I want to speedup a CPU-bound computation while `async` is mainly for IO-bound computation.

Comment: Jon: This may sound lame, but you could copy each slice of the array before passing it to the worker. What solution would you propose?

Comment: @pad: It's trivial to switch this to work with `Task`s, which perform better for CPU bound computations (but have a slightly less desirable syntax).

Comment: @pad: I changed it to use `Task`.

Comment: @Daniel: You approach looks much appealing now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The F# Powerpack has PSeq.exists which maps to PLINQ's ParallelEnumerable.Any which is part of the BCL. There's also ParallelEnumerable.First

I tried to decompile but wouldn't understand right away what was going on. So instead I went and executed the following side-effecting code to confirm that it's using some sort of cancellation once it found the element:

```
let elems = seq {
    for x = 0 to 1000000 do
        printfn "test"
        yield x }

open System
open System.Linq;;

ParallelEnumerable.First (ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel(elems), Func<_,_>(fun x -> x = 1))
```

Comment: I'm aware of `PSeq` but I'm more interested in a solution working directly on the array. In this way, I can avoid the cost of type casting and have more control over degree of parallelism.